# Nuxt loading bar not showing between routes

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, nuxt.js

The loading bar is enabled in nuxt.config.js as seen below, but it's not showing up between routes. I'm using Vuetify.

```
/*
** Customize the progress-bar color
*/
loading: {
  color: '#333333'
},
```

I'm using the following way to switch routes:

```
<nuxt-link to="/auth/admin">Admin</nuxt-link>
```

Comment: any console errors?

Comment: Is this a new project? because if so then the progress bar doesn't have a chance to pop up because of it's [throttle](https://nuxtjs.org/api/configuration-loading/#customize-the-progress-bar) property which sets a delay before showing the bar and if the request is completed in less than 200ms (its default value) it then doesn't pop up.

Comment: if you use
    loading: {
      color: '#333333',
      duration: 3000
    } does it show?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

same problem I have it

this is working for me

```
loading: { color: '#333333', throttle: 0 },
```

for more info [Customize progress bar](https://nuxtjs.org/api/configuration-loading/#customize-the-progress-bar)

Answer (score 7):

Try this:

```
loading: {
 color: 'blue',
 height: '5px',
 throttle: 0
}
```

But if you use

> Npx nuxt-create {app name}

Then in nuxt.config on line 20, there is already a loading object remove that.
Good luck.